# Lock pages in memory for multiple instances on single server

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2017

We have 8 instances out of which 6 are SQL Server 2014, 1 is SQL Server 2017 and all servers are running on Windows Server 2012 R2. The min and max memory set correctly for SQL Server 2014 & 2017. However, one of our DBAs enabled lock pages in memory for SQL Server 2017, but rest do not have this counter enabled.

There is one instance which sometime run into a problem "insufficient memory to process the thread" on same box.

What would be the recommendation for lock pages in memory for server with multiple instances? Should we enable it or not, even if we set min and max memory correctly.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/12/consulting-lines-pilot-dog/  : "“With LPIM, SQLOS will back down its usage to your ‘min server memory’ value. At that point Windows can try and hard trim the other processes, and potentially page the process requiring the 30GB memory out, or if it can’t respond efficiently this way, you may face a crash due to Out Of Memory for the OS."

Comment: @MitchWheat, the sql server instance with LPIM disabled is facing this problem. Is SQL Server 2017 with LPIM enabled is related to it ?

Comment: i would assume so. But I can't give you a 100% answer fro the info you have provided.

Comment: Hi @MitchWheat, First of all thanks for your responses :) . Let me try to explain again.There are 8 instances on same server with Windows server 2012 R2, 7 SQL Server 2014 and 1 SQL Server 2017. After analysis, we set min and max memory setting for all 8 SQL instances. LPIM is only enabled for SQL Server 2017. Now, one of the SQL Server 2014 instance is facing problem: There is insufficient memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query. I understand that query need more memory to process but will disabling LPIM for SQL 2017 will help ? Can SQL 2017 LPIM could be causing this problem ?

Comment: straight off, i would never recommend "... 8 instances on same server with Windows server 2012 R2"

Comment: Hi @MitchWheat, Thanks for your quick responses.